# System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Debug() stopped working

Tags: c#, debugging

I'm working on a program which uses the System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() method to allow the user to set a breakpoint from the command-line.  This has worked fine for many weeks now.  However, when I was working on fixing a unit test today, I tried to use the debug switch from the command-line, and it didn't work.

Here's what I've tried:

- I've confirmed that the Debug() method is really being called (by putting a System.Console.WriteLine() after it)
- I've confirmed that the build is still in Debug
- I've done a clean build
- I've restarted Product Studio

A quick Google search didn't reveal anything, and the API documentation for .Net doesn't mention anything about this function not performing correctly.  So... any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I finally figured out what was happening.  For some reason, something changed on my machine so that just calling `Debugger.Break` wasn't sufficient anymore (still don't understand what changed).  In any case, I can now cause the debugger to come up by using:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached == false) Debugger.Launch();
```

Comment: I've run into this same issue migrating from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010.  `Debugger.Break()` worked fine in VS2008; for VS2010, I'm now using `Debugger.Launch()`.

Comment: Same in VS2015 - Debugger.Break() didn't work - Debugger.Launch() worked

Comment: FWIW and for other idiots like myself, in my case it was because the code I was running was not the code I was looking at (similar code, different file...)

Comment: This worked for me when
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
did not. In my case, I think that was because I was debugging an exe running with elevated permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I was using `Debugger.Launch()` method and it stopped working suddenly. Using

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached == false) Debugger.Launch();
```

as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2734204) also did not bring up the debugger.

I tried resetting my Visual Studio settings and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Extracted from here ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.break)) the following note:

> Starting with .NET Framework 4, the runtime no longer exercises tight control of launching the debugger for the `Break` method, but instead reports an error to the Windows Error Reporting (WER) subsystem. WER provides many settings to customize the problem reporting experience, so a lot of factors will influence the way WER responds to an error such as operating system version, process, session, user, machine and domain. If you're having unexpected results when calling the `Break` method, check the WER settings on your machine. For more information on how to customize WER, see [WER Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/wer-settings). If you want to ensure the debugger is launched regardless of the WER settings, be sure to call the `Launch` method instead.

I think it explains the behavior detected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VS 2008 SP1?  I had a lot of problems around debugging in that release, and all of them were solved by this [Microsoft patch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957912).

> Breakpoints put in loops or in
>   recursive functions are not hit in all
>   processes at each iteration.
>   Frequently, some processes may pass
>   through many iterations of a loop,
>   ignoring the breakpoint, before a
>   process is stopped.
>
> Breakpoints are hit, but they are not
>   visible when you debug multiple
>   processes in the Visual Studio
>   debugger.

There are a few other debugger-related problems also fixed.

Comment: Sorry... after installing the patch, I'm still seeing the problem.  :-(