# Debug an application that was launched via explorer context menu

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a C# application that can be launched from the windows explorer context menu when certain file types are selected:

[image: screenshot]

I need to be able debug the application from the first line of code (ie I don't have time to launch it and attach to process) Is it possible to debug my application in visual studio when I launch it from the context menu?

Comment: Have a look [Attach to Running Processes with the Visual Studio Debugge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty please see my comments on Philipp's answer

Comment: You could also provide commandline arguments to your exe in the project start options and hit F5 unless ofcourse you want to verify if parameter passed is correct.

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat Yes I wanted to check the parameters that were passed to the application when launched via the context menu

Comment: Debug.WriteLine is very useful in these kind of scenarios. You could use DbgView from Sysinternals to view the debug output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the application is already running, just select Debug -> Attach to Process and then pick the process from the list.

If you are trying to debug the startup code of your application, you will need to try another approach because the code will be done executing by the time you are able to attach to the process.  In this case, if you are able to modify the code (and it sounds like you are), I would recommend adding this code somewhere in your application startup:

```
Debugger.Break();
```

When the process hits this line, it will pop up the dialog which says "would you like to debug?" and you can say yes and it will attach the Visual Studio debugger, with execution paused at that line.

Here is the docs for the Break() method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This sounds promising, however once I add this line of code and launch my application I get an error stating my application has stopped working.

Comment: Reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474739/system-diagnostics-debugger-debug-stopped-working I used if (Debugger.IsAttached == false) Debugger.Launch(); instead and it works

Comment: Great, glad you got it working.  I'm not sure why Launch() works but Break() doesn't... they should both work.

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft documentation for Debugger.Break() method:
Warning
Starting with .NET Framework 4, the runtime no longer exercises tight control of launching the debugger for the Break method, but instead reports an error to the Windows Error Reporting (WER) subsystem. WER provides many settings to customize the problem reporting experience, so a lot of factors will influence the way WER responds to an error such as operating system version, process, session, user, machine and domain. If you're having unexpected results when calling the Break method, check the WER settings on your machine. For more information on how to customize WER, see WER Settings. If you want to ensure the debugger is launched regardless of the WER settings, be sure to call the Launch method instead.