# .NET How to debug Application protocol handler?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, protocol-handler

I am creating application protocol handler using MSDN article
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx
but i can't debug my code. Please help me in how to debug the code. note the application is launched from the browser using my custom Schema URL.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run your application with a suitable argument. Set it in the project's properties and hit run. This will have the same effect as if the process were started by the browser.

[image: project properties]

Alternatively, run it from the browser and then attach the debugger to your process.

[image: attach]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but when i attach the debugger to chrome process , nothing happened

Comment: Don't attach it to the chrome process, you have to attach it to *your* process, the one chrome launches.

Comment: Hi, but i want to debug my Main method and in this case, the main method already run

Comment: Well, then either use the first method (it's the better one anyway), or put `Debugger.Break()` as the first instruction in your `Main` method

Comment: As your debugger is not attached yet, you should use `Debugger.Launch()` instead of `Debugger.Break()` to start a new Visual Studio instance or attach an existing on to the process, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474739/system-diagnostics-debugger-debug-stopped-working, or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a94a9e0a-ce6f-4136-8a27-a9085d458254/systemdiagnosticsdebuggerbreak-not-working-after-upgrading-to-vs-2010-from-vs-2008