# Is there a way to simulate an autostart with visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on a program (c# in Visual Studio), which has a strange behaviour.
I implemented a feature, that starts the program on windows start up (autostart).
For that I add in the registry path:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
The filepath of the program.

And it starts on start up.

But the App Crashes. When I start it manually - it works perfectly.

I dont understand, why the app has a different behaviour when I start it manually or with autostart. (I am using no parameters)

So I would like to debug it while simulating this autostart, but i dont know how to.

I am currently working on a logwriter, to see where the problem is, but it would be better, if I can debug it somehow.

The Eventlog (german), when the app crash on autostart, tells me:

```
 Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: myapp.exe, Version:19.4.25.0, Zeitstempel: 0x5cc1a6d1 Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: KERNELBASE.dll, Version: 6.2.17134.556, Zeitstempel: 0xb9f4a0f1
 Ausnahmecode: 0xe053534f 
 Fehleroffset: 0x000000000003a388 
 ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0x%9 
 Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x%10 
 Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: %11 
 Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: %12 
 Berichtskennung: %13 
 Vollständiger Name des fehlerhaften Pakets: %14 
 Anwendungs-ID, die relativ zum fehlerhaften Paket ist: %15
```

I'm not getting clever out of it, too.

Maybe you have some hints for me - best if you can show me a possiblity to simulate the autostart in order to debug the app:)

Comment: I suspect permissins are an issue. What user account is used to do autostart? and is it the same account that runs the app without autostart?

Comment: i have the problem on every user account. currently i am testing with my account (admin).
The program can be started manually by every user (no admin needed)

But autostart does not work. App crashes on every user.

Comment: Maybe something to do with the "current directory" which is different when you start it manually vs. when windows starts it? You can try logging it in your program when it starts.
Also, possibly you can try debugging your program when window starts (add Debugger.Break() in the beginning of your program, that you can attach visual studio).

Comment: thank you for the hint Metheny. This can help me. But i guess i`m too stupid to use it ._. 

I put System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); on program start but it does nothing :o
It just gets ignored and the program starts.
Is there anything else i have to pay attention?

Comment: @nninja: Hmm, according to this link it changed to: Debugger.Launch()
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474739/system-diagnostics-debugger-debug-stopped-working

Comment: That helped me, much.
thx!
I see now, i'm using a relative path that is saved in the registry. 
But when i autostart the program, it does not use that relative path. It uses somehow the system32 path. 
I have to check my code but i m sure i can solve it now. 

Was pretty annoying to find the problem without debuging :P